# Transpose pivot table

Tags: pandas

I have this pivot table `df_pivot`:

```
                          sum      
                       points
team        position                       
Liverpool    fwd       66.1   
             gkp       8.6   
             mid       33.9   
             def       45.2
```

How do I transpose the table in order to get:

```
team       fwd   gkp  mid   def
Liverpool  66.1  8.6  33.9  45.2
```

Comment: can you try `df_pivot.unstack()`

Comment: df_pivot.iloc[:,0].unstack()

Comment: Also seems like you might be accidentally defining a few of the `pivot_table` arguments as lists leading to a MultiIndex when using just the string would prevent the unnecessary levels (i.e. use `aggfunc='sum'` not `aggfunc=['sum']`)